# Node.js / MongoDB Filter date range

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to filter query by date range dynamically parameters from GET

```
var date_from = req.query['date_from'];
var date_to = req.query['date_to'];
var options = {};
if(date_from){
        if(!options["sentDateTime"]) options["sentDateTime"] = [];
    var dateFrom = moment(new Date(date_from)).toDate();
        options["sentDateTime"]['$qte'] = dateFrom;
}

if(date_to){
    if(!options["sentDateTime"]) options["sentDateTime"] = [];
    var dateTo = moment(new Date(date_to)).toDate();
        options["sentDateTime"]['$lte'] = dateTo;
}
```

For example my options look like

```
{ sentDateTime: { '$qte': Tue Mar 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT) } }
```

Rest of code

```
db.client.collection('mails_ed').find(options).limit(parseInt(req.query['limit'])).toArray(function(err, docs) {
// ...
})
```

But it return zero documents.

Edit:

After changes my object look like this

```
{ sentDateTime:
   [ '$qte': Tue Mar 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
     '$lte': Fri Mar 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT) ]
 }
```

As you can see that options wrap into array '[]' how can i fix it?

Comment: That's not a valid ISO date string for Mongo. Wrap the moment object in `new Date`, not vice versa. `new Date(moment(date_to).utc())` worked for me

Comment: Thanks for comment. I go with that solution but still something wrong. I think maybe in object options look how it look now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use curly braces instead of square brackets to create an object literal. Also, I think you meant `$gte` rather than `$qte`?

```
var date_from = req.query['date_from'];
var date_to = req.query['date_to'];
var options = {};
if(date_from){
        if(!options["sentDateTime"]) options["sentDateTime"] = {};
    var dateFrom = moment(new Date(date_from)).toDate();
        options["sentDateTime"]['$gte'] = dateFrom;
}

if(date_to){
    if(!options["sentDateTime"]) options["sentDateTime"] = {};
    var dateTo = moment(new Date(date_to)).toDate();
        options["sentDateTime"]['$lte'] = dateTo;
}
```